# App crashes when I scroll the ListView again and again

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter, android-cursoradapter, android-cursorloader

I have used a list view and there are more than 65,000 records, scrolling is not done fast and smooth, and also if I scroll it again and again the app crashes, without any error or any ANR dialog box, can anybody help me to resolve that issue?

I am using `SimpleCursorLoader` and  `CursorAdapter`  and below is my code:

```
   private static class DotCursorLoader extends SimpleCursorLoader {

    private DbHelper mHelper;
    private CharSequence filter;

    public DotCursorLoader(Context context, DbHelper helper,
            CharSequence filter) {
        super(context);
        mHelper = helper;
        this.filter = filter;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor loadInBackground() {

        return mHelper.getCursor(filter);
    }

}

private class DotCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private Typeface font;

    public class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtEng, txtGuj;
    }

    // public DotCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
    // super(context, c, flags);
    // mContext = context;
    // }

    public DotCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c,
            boolean autoRequery) {
        super(context, c, autoRequery);
        mContext = context;

    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context,
            android.database.Cursor cursor) {
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        if (LibConstants.isEnglishEnabled(mActivity)) {

            holder.txtEng.setTextColor(settings.getInt(
                    LibConstants.English_Pref_Color_Key,
                    Color.BLACK));
            // txtEng.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            holder.txtEng.setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(settings
                    .getString("TextSize", "20")));
            holder.txtEng.setText(LibConstants.getWord(cursor
                    .getString(1)));
            Utils.setEnglishFont(holder.txtEng, mActivity);

            holder.txtGuj.setTextColor(settings.getInt(
                    LibConstants.Mean_Pref_Color_Key,
                    getResources().getInteger(
                            R.color.blue)));

            holder.txtGuj.setTypeface(font);
            holder.txtGuj.setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(settings
                    .getString("TextSize", "20")));
            holder.txtGuj.setText(LibConstants.getWord(cursor
                    .getString(2)));

        } else {

            holder.txtEng.setTextColor(settings
                    .getInt(LibConstants.Mean_Pref_Color_Key,
                            getResources().getColor(
                                    R.color.blue)));
            holder.txtEng.setTypeface(font);
            holder.txtEng.setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(settings
                    .getString("TextSize", "20")));
            holder.txtEng.setText((cursor
                    .getString(2)));

            holder.txtGuj.setTextColor(settings.getInt(
                    LibConstants.English_Pref_Color_Key,
                    Color.BLACK));
            holder.txtGuj.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT);
            holder.txtGuj.setTextSize(Integer.parseInt(settings
                    .getString("TextSize", "20")));
            holder.txtGuj.setText(cursor
                    .getString(1));
            Utils.setEnglishFont(holder.txtGuj, mActivity);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context,
            android.database.Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.txtEng = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txtEng);
        viewHolder.txtGuj = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txtGuj);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you show the output of logcat? There must be some error if the application has crashed

Comment: @helleye no there is no any error is generating and no any exception is throwing just app goes away :(

Comment: But something should at least point out that the application(activity) was destroyed

Comment: @helleye if i scroll it slowly slowly, again and again so many times,  it is not crashing, but at faster scrolling it is crashing

Comment: May be due to low memory . Increase memory of the app may solve your issue or Use pagination instead of loading 65000 item at a time.

Comment: You are using the `font` variable but I don't see you initialising it anywhere. Also, what does Utils.setEnglishFont do? Are you loading a typeface repeatedly there? (also I believe there may be memory leaks in the platform when using custom fonts).

Comment: Please post code of `Utils.setEnglishFont` method.

Answer (score 1):

One of the best example of Endless Adapter can be found here

https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless

Answer (score 1):

try this.while scrolling you have to recycle the view
NOTE:i have not tested, it may work...

```
View con=null; 
 class ViewHolder
     {

         TextView tv,tv1;
         public ViewHolder(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

                tv=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.phone_number); 
                tv1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.contact_name);


        }
     }
     //
      @Override
    public View newView(Context context,
            android.database.Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder viewHolder ;
            if(con==null)
            {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(
                R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
                con=view;
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(con);

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
         Log.i("getview","new view created");
        }

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this using a load more button after lets say 25 records, and each time the listview would load another 25 records. The example [here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/) is one of the best for this kind of implementation.

You could also use the swipe to refresh api availabel on GitHub.

Comment: I would not consider a "load more button", but automatically load more as an "Endless" adapter would do.

Comment: It is doable to load a next set of 25 results upon reaching the bottom of the listview.

Comment: Could you please accept and upvote this answer please if it has helped you?